# Appended value in array is not desired value in c

Tags: c, arrays, struct, append

This function appends a desired value to the end of the array.  When I tested the code, I used the value 100776, but when I printed out the array, the value of the last element was 135009, which is completely different than what my desired value was.  Does anybody know why that's the case?

Here is the struct for my append function:

```
typedef struct {
  int* data;
  unsigned int len;
} intarr_t;
```

And this is my actual append function:

```
intarr_result_t intarr_push( intarr_t* ia, int val )
{
    unsigned int len = ia->len;
    if (ia == NULL)
    {
        return INTARR_BADARRAY;
    }
    else
    {
        ia->data = realloc(ia->data, (sizeof(int)*len+1));
        if (ia->data != 0)
        {
            ia->data[len+1]=val;
            ia->len=len+1;
            assert (ia->data);
            return INTARR_OK;
        }
        else
        {
            return INTARR_BADALLOC;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: where's the code that calls it?

Comment: @JohnClaser: I think that you should use `sizeof(int)*(len+1)` inside your `realloc` function. And then `ia->data[len]=val`.

Comment: John, If you want to add to your question, that's fine, but please do not edit your question **so it reflects the answer**. That destroys any learning potential your question may have provided to others. If you want to **add to** your question to show **hey, I got it!**, that's fine, but do it **below** your original question so that the original answers and comments continue to make sense. They don't now. The first suggestion and answer was `sizeof(int)*(len+1)` inside your `realloc`. Anybody that looks now will have no idea what that was in response to.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Hi David, I'm not quite sure what you mean. I didnt edit my question at all. I just got home and I'm just looking at the suggestions right now.

Comment: Well maybe I ate too much turkey.  But I was trying to follow along with your question and I see the comment saying you should use `sizeof(int)*(len+1)` in your `realloc`, I look and that is what is there and that leaves me scratching my head?? I may have made a bad assumption. There have been numerous cases lately of people changing their questions after getting an answer doing what I describe. If you didn't, then my apologies, just keep doing what you're doing then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

given you have:-

```
(sizeof(int)*len+1)
```

then this is off the end of your array :-

```
ia->data[len+1]=val;
```

for two reasons :-

- you haven't allocated enough memory because the + 1 occurs after the multiplication.
- if you allocate 1 then your first spot is data[0]  not data[1].

so you should do :-

```
a->data = realloc(ia->data, (sizeof(int)*(len+1)));
```

and

```
ia->data[len]=val;
ia->len++;
```

and your last item is  `ia->data[ia->len-1];`

Comment: For the value that was added to the end of the array, what value is that? Because I didn't ask it to add that value.

Comment: you didn't show the calling code, so not sure, but if you got mixed up like you did in this function, and like my answer says, your last item is at length-1, if you were getting the item at length, it's just random memory